# Azure ADLS - azcopy copy inside Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I don't have permission to get access keys for containers.Due to this unable to use "azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient".I can use only ContainerClient class using SAS key.

I can copy data including subfolder using "azure azcopy" on the command prompt from a windows machine.
subfolder:456 and data copied to target adls container using below command.

azcopy copy "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[source_container]/abc/def/123/tst/456?[SAS]" "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[target_container]/tgttst?[SAS]"

Please let me know how to automate to create subfolder on target ADLS and to copy data inside Python script.

Thanks in advance.

getting an error message "Attribute Error: 'BlobClient' object has no attribute create_container"

```
    from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient 
    sas_url="[account].blob.core.windows.net/[target_container]/tgttst?[SAS]"  
container=ContainerClient.from_container_url(sas_url) 
container_client = container.get_blob_client("abc/def/123") 
container_client.create_container()
```

Note : SAS token has READ/WRITE/LIST privileges

Comment: you could use the ```subproces``` module to run the ```azcopy``` command.

Comment: Provided you have proper permissions in your SAS Token, you should be able to create folders and copy blobs using `ContainerClient`. What issues are you running into when using ContainerClient?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri: Thanks for reply.
I am getting error message "Attribute Error: 'BlobClient' object has no attribute create_container"

from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient
sas_url="https://accountname.blob.core........"
container=ContainerClient.from_container_url_sas_url)

container_client = container.get_blob_client("abc/123")

container_client.create_container()

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written.

Comment: Also share the permissions in your SAS token.

Comment: I have READ and WRITE privileges.

Comment: Please do not put code in comments. Edit your question and include it there only.

Comment: Updated code in question,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, thanks for your help:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

def azure_connect_sas_url(source_container_sas_url, source_container_name):
    try:
        blob_source_service_client = BlobServiceClient(source_container_sas_url)
        source_container_client = blob_source_service_client.get_container_client(source_container_name)
        print ("SAS URL -- Connected.")
        return source_container_client

    except Exception as ex:
        print ("Error: " + str(ex))

def main():
    try:
        azure_sas_url = input ('Please enter SAS URL: ')
        container_name = input ('Please enter Container name: ')

        ## SAS URL
        connection_instance = azure_connect_sas_url(azure_sas_url, container_name)

        print ('Done')
        
    except Exception as ex:
        print ('main | Error: ', ex)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```